# Is there any driver available for Radeon XPRESS 200(M)?

Tags: drivers, radeon

I have a problem with my graphic card `Radeon XPRESS 200(M)` on Ubuntu 12.10. As far as I know, there isn't any driver which would support this card any more.

So I will appreciate if any of you can help me find a driver for it. I have already read a similar question about this card and none of them helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: could you be more specific? what is that you are trying and what is that problem you are facing.

Comment: You know that it will only work with the open-source driver, what can we do for you. To help you solve an issue you need to tell us what the issue is...

Comment: Thank you guys, i'm running unity and its so slow sometimes and in the middle of playing movies suddenly the whole thing is crash and said something about radeon graphic card, the message disappeared so fast that i can't read the rest of the message , then i have to restart the Ubuntu

Comment: I don't know if this is still any issue for you, but in my notebook I have Radeon Xpress 1100 graphics card, the next in line successor to your graphics card. AMD's proprietary drivers aren't compatible with current versions of x.org (anything you'd find in any of the supported versions of Ubuntu) and AMD has announced that they will no long provide updates for Linux drivers on these legacy cards (they did so quite some time ago). However, using the open source drivers, I'm able to run World of Warcraft quite, so they aren't bad.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think FGLRX will work. I think it will not even show on the restricted drivers section either. In my humble opinion, stick with the open source drivers. It will work without problem. But you can overclock or downclock your card using Rovclock app on software center. I already had one Express 200M and i used rovclock to gain a few more frames on some old games.
(Use Rovclock with caution to not burn your graphics card)
Edit: you dont need to install nothing in order to use the open source driver. it comes preinstalled on your ubuntu installation!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

AMD does not make propriety Linux drivers for this device any more. However, the open source drivers would probably be better for something so old anyway:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```